# Does a function $f(x)$ exist such that $f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. And if so what is it.

Tags: functions

I have done a fair bit of thinking on this.
Lets say that $z(f(x))=f(x+1)-f(x)$.
I figured out that $z\left(\frac{x^2-x}{2}\right)=x$.
But one over that does not equal $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: dear ggbg, I have seen you at mathoverflow asking about tetration.
1) going to mathoverflow when your reputation or experience is very low is something i do not recommend.
2) as for tetration , you asked for a plot , but there are infinitely many tetrations !! So as stated the question was not solvable.
3) For tetration there is the tetration forum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Let $L(z)$ denote the logarithm of the gamma function.

Then $L(x + 1) - L(x) = \log(x)$.  So the derivative $L'(x)$ (i.e. $\Gamma'(x) / \Gamma(x)$) satisfies the desired functional equation.

Comment: Great answer! Just in case someone wants to know more about $L(z)$, it's also known as the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: What's the domain of this function? It's not defined where $\Gamma(x)<0$. Of course, the original question runs into trouble at $x=0$, anyway.